# solving contour integration problem in Stein Complex analysis exercise 5 of chapter 3

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to solve a question in stein complex analysis which is stated as follows:

> Use contour integration to show that
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi ix\xi}}{(1
> +x^2)^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}(1+2\pi |\xi|)e^{-2\pi|\xi|}$$
> for all $\xi$ real.

I tried to solve this by doing contour integral of $f(z)=\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{-2\pi iz\xi}}{(1
+z^2)^2}dz$ over upper half circle containing the pole at $x=i$ but came to a trouble because I wasn't sure how to use the residue theorem to get the value of this contour integration. I know that I have to differentiate the integrand in the process to use the residue theorem but was not sure how do so for the case where the pole has order 2. (Also, not exactly sure how to complex differentiate the exponential function.)

Also, I thought the upper half circle curve integration will make the integration go to 0 but now I am not sure as I cannot seemed to find suitable inequality condition to show it.

Thanks.

Comment: I think there is a small typo on the RHS, there should be no $x$ in the exponent. To find the residue of higher order poles, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles). Alternatively you could write out the Laurent series for the integrand about $x=\pm i$ and pick out the coefficient of $1/x$. Also note that when $\xi >0$ you need to close the contour in the lower half plane and vice versa

Comment: @Sal You are totally right! Sorry for the confusion. So hard to type without error lol... Thank you for the help

Comment: I just fixed it!